# Running out of memory with plenty of memory and swap

Tags: linux, memory-leak, virtual-memory, oom, oom-killer

I have a Debian-based system that is running out of memory but there appears to be plenty of free memory. The box will run for about 6-12 days and then it will begin killing anything allocating memory (usually allocating `skbs`). Eventually, it kills Xorg and it degenerates into a watchdog reboot, then the box will run another 6-12 days before seeing the same failure.

Here is the oom-killer log:

```
[521652.462829] Xorg invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x400cc0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[521652.462841] CPU: 1 PID: 28603 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G         C        5.4.59-v7l+ #37
[521652.462844] Hardware name: BCM2711
[521652.462847] Backtrace:
[521652.462864] [<c020dfb0>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c020e318>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[521652.462869]  r7:ffffffff r6:00000000 r5:60000013 r4:c129dc94
[521652.462877] [<c020e2f8>] (show_stack) from [<c0a4ca0c>] (dump_stack+0xd8/0x11c)
[521652.462887] [<c0a4c934>] (dump_stack) from [<c0381478>] (dump_header+0x64/0x200)
[521652.462892]  r10:00000000 r9:00001400 r8:c12a0090 r7:c0dd8104 r6:c2a93c80 r5:eee7bd00
[521652.462896]  r4:cf0e1c68 r3:7747a280
[521652.462903] [<c0381414>] (dump_header) from [<c0380834>] (oom_kill_process+0x178/0x184)
[521652.462907]  r7:c0dd8104 r6:cf0e1c68 r5:eee7c250 r4:eee7bd00
[521652.462914] [<c03806bc>] (oom_kill_process) from [<c03812c8>] (out_of_memory+0x27c/0x33c)
[521652.462918]  r7:c1208380 r6:cf0e1c68 r5:c1204f88 r4:eee7bd00
[521652.462927] [<c038104c>] (out_of_memory) from [<c03cef78>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0xc18/0x1288)
[521652.462931]  r7:00000000 r6:c120508c r5:0000fe2b r4:00000000
[521652.462941] [<c03ce360>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<c08eebb8>] (alloc_skb_with_frags+0xdc/0x1a4)
[521652.462945]  r10:c551f840 r9:00008000 r8:004008c0 r7:00000000 r6:00000008 r5:00000008
[521652.462948]  r4:00000003
[521652.462955] [<c08eeadc>] (alloc_skb_with_frags) from [<c08e6518>] (sock_alloc_send_pskb+0x214/0x248)
[521652.462960]  r10:cf0e1d7c r9:c1204f88 r8:c026d33c r7:cf0e1dcc r6:ffffe000 r5:00000000
[521652.462964]  r4:d799ea00
[521652.462973] [<c08e6304>] (sock_alloc_send_pskb) from [<c0a02e40>] (unix_stream_sendmsg+0x144/0x3a0)
[521652.462978]  r10:d799ea00 r9:d799e700 r8:00000f00 r7:cf0e1dcc r6:c551fb40 r5:00008f00
[521652.462981]  r4:00008000
[521652.462987] [<c0a02cfc>] (unix_stream_sendmsg) from [<c08e1690>] (sock_write_iter+0xb0/0x114)
[521652.462991]  r10:eee3c900 r9:d4722d00 r8:cf0e1e38 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c1204f88
[521652.462994]  r4:cf0e1ed4
[521652.463002] [<c08e15e0>] (sock_write_iter) from [<c03f9734>] (do_iter_readv_writev+0x168/0x1d4)
[521652.463006]  r10:00000000 r9:cf0e1f60 r8:c1204f88 r7:00000000 r6:eee3c900 r5:00000000
[521652.463009]  r4:00000000
[521652.463016] [<c03f95cc>] (do_iter_readv_writev) from [<c03faa4c>] (do_iter_write+0x94/0x1a4)
[521652.463020]  r10:00000001 r9:bed31b84 r8:cf0e1f60 r7:00000000 r6:eee3c900 r5:cf0e1ed4
[521652.463023]  r4:00000000
[521652.463030] [<c03fa9b8>] (do_iter_write) from [<c03fac2c>] (vfs_writev+0x9c/0xe8)
[521652.463034]  r9:bed31b84 r8:cf0e1f60 r7:eee3c900 r6:cf0e1ed4 r5:0001a780 r4:c1204f88
[521652.463041] [<c03fab90>] (vfs_writev) from [<c03face8>] (do_writev+0x70/0x144)
[521652.463045]  r8:eee3c900 r7:00000092 r6:00000000 r5:eee3c901 r4:c1204f88
[521652.463052] [<c03fac78>] (do_writev) from [<c03fc4d4>] (sys_writev+0x1c/0x20)
[521652.463056]  r10:00000092 r9:cf0e0000 r8:c02011c4 r6:0000002e r5:bed31b84 r4:00000001
[521652.463064] [<c03fc4b8>] (sys_writev) from [<c0201000>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
[521652.463068] Exception stack(0xcf0e1fa8 to 0xcf0e1ff0)
[521652.463072] 1fa0:                   00000001 bed31b84 0000002e bed31b84 00000001 00000000
[521652.463077] 1fc0: 00000001 bed31b84 0000002e 00000092 00000001 00000000 b6fcf6f4 00000000
[521652.463081] 1fe0: 00000002 bed318f8 00000000 b69f1654
[521652.463085] Mem-Info:
[521652.463097] active_anon:27936 inactive_anon:40717 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:9032 inactive_file:15510 isolated_file:0
                 unevictable:22734 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                 slab_reclaimable:3248 slab_unreclaimable:7041
                 mapped:27349 shmem:61689 pagetables:1321 bounce:0
                 free:253912 free_pcp:34 free_cma:60386
[521652.463106] Node 0 active_anon:111744kB inactive_anon:162868kB active_file:36128kB inactive_file:62040kB unevictable:90936kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:109396kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:246756kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
[521652.463117] DMA free:258884kB min:20480kB low:24576kB high:28672kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:404kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:786432kB managed:679084kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:2280kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:136kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:241544kB
[521652.463122] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 1204 1204
[521652.463139] HighMem free:756764kB min:512kB low:7948kB high:15384kB active_anon:111480kB inactive_anon:162868kB active_file:35840kB inactive_file:61440kB unevictable:90820kB writepending:0kB present:1232896kB managed:1232896kB mlocked:44kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:5284kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[521652.463143] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[521652.463155] DMA: 356*4kB (UE) 786*8kB (UEC) 683*16kB (UEC) 28*32kB (UEC) 19*64kB (UEC) 8*128kB (C) 5*256kB (C) 2*512kB (C) 6*1024kB (C) 2*2048kB (C) 55*4096kB (C) = 259600kB
[521652.463197] HighMem: 322*4kB (UM) 3624*8kB (UM) 3968*16kB (UM) 2072*32kB (UM) 2012*64kB (UM) 1118*128kB (UM) 376*256kB (UM) 132*512kB (M) 40*1024kB (M) 19*2048kB (UM) 20*4096kB (UM) = 757576kB
[521652.463238] 86322 total pagecache pages
[521652.463246] 0 pages in swap cache
[521652.463252] Swap cache stats: add 36, delete 36, find 10/14
[521652.463257] Free swap  = 2121980kB
[521652.463262] Total swap = 2122748kB
[521652.463267] 504832 pages RAM
[521652.463272] 308224 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[521652.463277] 26837 pages reserved
[521652.463281] 65536 pages cma reserved
```

There is no memory fragmentation as shown here:

```
[521652.463155] DMA: 356*4kB (UE) 786*8kB (UEC) 683*16kB (UEC) 28*32kB (UEC) 19*64kB (UEC) 8*128kB (C) 5*256kB (C) 2*512kB (C) 6*1024kB (C) 2*2048kB (C) 55*4096kB (C) = 259600kB
[521652.463197] HighMem: 322*4kB (UM) 3624*8kB (UM) 3968*16kB (UM) 2072*32kB (UM) 2012*64kB (UM) 1118*128kB (UM) 376*256kB (UM) 132*512kB (M) 40*1024kB (M) 19*2048kB (UM) 20*4096kB (UM) = 757576kB
```

Here is the `gfp_mask` decoded:

```
 Xorg invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x400cc0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT), order=0, oom_score_adj=0

Order = 0 means allocating 4kb pages

 0x400cc0

 4: ___GFP_THISNODE     
 C: ___GFP_KSWAPD_RECLAIM, ___GFP_DIRECT_RECLAIM, 
 C: ___GFP_IO, ___GFP_FS        
 0: ZONE_NORMAL allocation
```

Here is the kernel `/proc/slabinfo`. Slabtop basically indicates no aggregating kernel memory so I don't think this is a kernel leak:

```
slabinfo - version: 2.1
# name            <active_objs> <num_objs> <objsize> <objperslab> <pagesperslab> : tunables <limit> <batchcount> <sharedfactor> : slabdata <active_slabs> <num_slabs> <sharedavail>
fuse_request         156    156    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
fuse_inode           112    112    576   28    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
PINGv6                 0      0    896   18    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
RAWv6                 36     36    896   18    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
UDPv6                 68     68    960   17    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
tw_sock_TCPv6          0      0    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
request_sock_TCPv6      0      0    240   17    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
TCPv6                 53     53   1920   17    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
ext4_groupinfo_4k     72     72    112   36    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
ovl_inode            722   1156    456   17    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     68     68      0
mqueue_inode_cache     25     25    640   25    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
discard_entry          0      0     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
nat_entry              0      0     24  170    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
f2fs_inode_cache       0      0    752   21    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
nfs_direct_cache       0      0    136   30    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
nfs_inode_cache        0      0    736   22    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
fat_inode_cache       64     64    496   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
fat_cache            680    680     24  170    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
squashfs_inode_cache    418    992    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     62     62      0
jbd2_inode           408    408     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
jbd2_journal_head    256    256     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
ext4_inode_cache     264    264    744   22    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     12     12      0
ext4_allocation_context    156    156    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
ext4_prealloc_space    224    224     72   56    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
ext4_io_end          340    340     48   85    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
ext4_pending_reservation    256    256     16  256    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
ext4_extent_status    512    512     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
mbcache              408    408     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kioctx                18     18    448   18    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
pid_namespace          0      0    120   34    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
posix_timers_cache     88     88    184   22    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
rpc_inode_cache       18     18    448   18    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
rpc_buffers           16     16   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
ip4-frags              0      0    136   30    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
xfrm_state            56     56    576   28    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
PING                 672    672    768   21    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     32     32      0
RAW                   63     63    768   21    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
UDP                  114    114    832   19    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      6      6      0
tw_sock_TCP           84     84    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
request_sock_TCP      68     68    240   17    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
TCP                  108    108   1792   18    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      6      6      0
cachefiles_object_jar      0      0    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
fscache_cookie_jar     42     42     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
dquot                 84     84    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
eventpoll_pwq        510    510     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      5      5      0
inotify_inode_mark    510    510     48   85    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      6      6      0
scsi_data_buffer       0      0     16  256    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
request_queue         46     46   1408   23    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
blkdev_ioc           256    256     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
biovec-max           100    100   3072   10    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     10     10      0
biovec-128            42     42   1536   21    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
biovec-64             84     84    768   21    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
user_namespace         0      0    376   21    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
sock_inode_cache     572    968    640   25    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     41     41      0
skbuff_fclone_cache    336    336    384   21    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     16     16      0
skbuff_head_cache  21690  21861    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   1041   1041      0
configfs_dir_cache     73     73     56   73    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
file_lock_cache      638    864    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     27     27      0
fsnotify_mark_connector    680    680     24  170    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
net_namespace          9      9   3456    9    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
task_delay_info     3264   3264     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     64     64      0
taskstats             92     92    344   23    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
proc_dir_entry       672    672    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     21     21      0
pde_opener           680    680     24  170    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
proc_inode_cache     198    360    440   18    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     20     20      0
seq_file             184    184     88   46    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
bdev_cache           112    112    576   28    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
shmem_inode_cache   2259   2431    456   17    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    143    143      0
kernfs_iattrs_cache   1512   1512     72   56    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     27     27      0
kernfs_node_cache  26334  26334     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    627    627      0
filp                3347   4788    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    228    228      0
inode_cache         9885  10460    400   20    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    523    523      0
dentry             14017  26190    136   30    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    873    873      0
names_cache           40     40   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      5      5      0
key_jar             1235   1365    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     65     65      0
buffer_head         1783   2176     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     34     34      0
uts_namespace          0      0    416   19    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
vm_area_struct      9393  10842    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    278    278      0
mm_struct            368    368    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     23     23      0
files_cache          384    384    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
signal_cache         575    575    704   23    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     25     25      0
sighand_cache        423    480   1344   24    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     20     20      0
task_struct          296    360   3904    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     45     45      0
cred_jar            1837   1952    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     61     61      0
anon_vma_chain      9461  10880     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     85     85      0
anon_vma            5761   6351     56   73    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     87     87      0
pid                 2432   2432     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     38     38      0
trace_event_file    1445   1445     48   85    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     17     17      0
radix_tree_node     3240   6708    304   26    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    258    258      0
task_group           192    192    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     12     12      0
vmap_area           8064   8064     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     63     63      0
dma-kmalloc-8k         0      0   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-4k         0      0   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-2k         0      0   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-1k         0      0   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-512        0      0    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-256        0      0    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-128        0      0    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-64       256    256     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
dma-kmalloc-192        0      0    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-8k         0      0   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-4k         0      0   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-2k         0      0   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-1k         0      0   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-512        0      0    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-256        0      0    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-192        0      0    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-rcl-128     2496   2496    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     78     78      0
kmalloc-rcl-64      2304   2304     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     36     36      0
kmalloc-8k            64     68   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     17     17      0
kmalloc-4k           588    612   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     80     80      0
kmalloc-2k           272    272   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     17     17      0
kmalloc-1k          1318   1392   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     87     87      0
kmalloc-512         2130   2200    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    138    138      0
kmalloc-256          660    752    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     47     47      0
kmalloc-192         1701   1701    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     81     81      0
kmalloc-128         2948   3392    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    106    106      0
kmalloc-64         25371  28928     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    452    452      0
kmem_cache_node      256    256     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmem_cache           144    144    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      9      9      0
```

Can anyone provide some assistance with what resource is running out? I haven't been able to determine even why the OOM killer is running. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

In response to comments:

The memory cgroup is not enabled, so it (shouldn't be) a cgroup issue:

```
cat /proc/cgroups
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpuset  4       1       1
cpu     2       1       1
cpuacct 2       1       1
blkio   7       1       1
memory  0       57      0
devices 5       39      1
freezer 6       1       1
net_cls 3       1       1
pids    8       46      1
```

Here is `/proc/meminfo`:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1911980 kB
MemFree:          734172 kB
MemAvailable:     890688 kB
Buffers:           16664 kB
Cached:           479784 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           395800 kB
Inactive:         273448 kB
Active(anon):     336436 kB
Inactive(anon):   111840 kB
Active(file):      59364 kB
Inactive(file):   161608 kB
Unevictable:      125944 kB
Mlocked:            7552 kB
HighTotal:       1232896 kB
HighFree:         446848 kB
LowTotal:         679084 kB
LowFree:          287324 kB
SwapTotal:        524284 kB
SwapFree:         524284 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        298848 kB
Mapped:           218932 kB
Shmem:            272964 kB
KReclaimable:      17748 kB
Slab:              43448 kB
SReclaimable:      17748 kB
SUnreclaim:        25700 kB
KernelStack:        2664 kB
PageTables:         5140 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1480272 kB
Committed_AS:    1766576 kB
VmallocTotal:     245760 kB
VmallocUsed:        6368 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              512 kB
CmaTotal:         262144 kB
CmaFree:          240632 kB
```

I've already tried adjusting `vm.overcommit_memory=2` and `vm.overcommit_ratio=2` to get a CommitLimit of 4GB on another box which is larger than my VM working set to rule out the heuristic overcommit algorithm having some issue. It still crashed in the same manner.

Comment: I wonder if this process is running in a memory controlled cgroup? Do you have a dump_tasks output also that goes along with this? Could you try enabling ```vm.oom_dump_tasks``` at least for next time?

Comment: Also, you might want to see if you've got any hugepages preallocated. Check the output of  ```/proc/meminfo```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I've added info. There is no memory cgroups (see edit) so it can't be that. I tried adding the task dump but it exceeds the character count supported by SF. I also added the /proc/meminfo and don't see hugepages listed.

Comment: I'm not particularly experienced with Raspberry Pi/Arm out of memory situations but it looks like something is being missed here (maybe theres a different GFP_MASK its using in another allocation process, or unaccounted for memory). You might be able to work it out through the use of `vm.panic_on_oom` and the `crash` package to debug the output. I suspect that the GFP_MASK being reported isn't the one that was attempted for an allocation.

Comment: Thanks, I will give vm.panic_on_oom a shot and try to trace it that way.